# Good OpenWRT alternative?

Tags: distribution-choice, embedded, openwrt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open Source router firmware options?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6277/open-source-router-firmware-options)

I own an ASUS wl-520gU (4 LAN, 1 WAN, WiFi, 1 USB, 4mb flash rom, 16mb ram. Broadcom BCM5354 @ 240). I am going to use it as a micro-computer rather than as a router. Currently I'm experimenting with WiFi radio.

I found that OpenWRT is causing my router to hang after ~30-60 minutes of being idle. DD-WRT is reported to behave in the same manner. And what I really dislike about OpenWRT - their forum is more about complaining users than helping developers — at least that's what I feel.

So, my requirements are:

- Linux with 2.6 kernel (needed for USB 2.0, as far as I understand), suiting the given specs, with good package manager and packages base.
- For modules I need USB 2.0, USB audio, USB HID, CP210x, USB Storage, EXT3.
- For programs I need python 2.6+, mpd, mpc.

I'm OK with building the system image from sources, if needed, but package manager is desired.

Add: I usually move all my packages to USB partition to increase space for them, so some pre-baked tool like extroot is good as well.

Comment: can you clarify why this is not a duplicate of [6277](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/6277/29)?

Comment: @xenoterracide OP hasn't been back since asking the question. It looks like a duplicate to me

Comment: @MichaelMrozek lol, I should be more careful. I didn't think to check the dates.

Answer (score 3):

OpenWRT and DDWRT are the two main distros in this category. I would encourage you to help find and fix the issue. If it's affecting both distros, it's likely to be a kernel problem that you would run into even if you built your own system from sources only.

It is unfortunate that the developer community is so small compared to the user base on these specialty distros, but the best way to fix that is to help reverse the trend. At the very least if you can pitch in to help with some more generic user problems maybe you can get some dev to help out with your harder problem.

Comment: Well, your words are wise. Unfortunately, I'm far from C++ and kernel dev. I can make some research and answer some questions, but there's nobody to ask these questions. I'm not the one running into this problem, I saw old tickets (may be a year old) with some patches etc., but the problem is still in fresh builds.

Comment: But yes, after some additional research I see there are no more mature distros available for embedded systems. And I'm ready to build something prepared, but not ready to compose a distro on my own.

Comment: I wouldn't expect you to jump in doing kernel level C++ programming. That's why I suggested helping other users at whatever level you can in an effort to add weight to your plea for some dev to help address the outstanding more technical issue.