# OpenWRT and Current Release Support

Tags: openwrt

## I'd like to install OpenWRT on an Asus WL-520GU router

I have a couple of Asus WL-520GU modems and Raspberry Pi (model B) boards floating around and I'd like to put some of them to use in some capacity around my  network.

I want to install OpenWRT and would prefer to use one of the Asus boxes. Actually, one already has an old release from 2008 on it—but I'd like to upgrade it to the latest as at the writing of this, 15.05. But I'm not quite understanding the compatibility of these devices in relation to the "Current Release Support" you see on various pages.

From the [Hardware Table](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start?dataflt%5BModel*%7E%5D=wl-520gu) search page for the device page for the [Asus WL-520GU](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/asus/wl520gu), it appears the latest support version is 10.03.1

Also in relation to the Raspberry Pi (model B), ([search](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start?dataflt%5BModel*%7E%5D=raspberry) and [device](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/raspberry_pi_foundation/raspberry_pi) pages), it would appear the latest supported version is 14.07.

## My question is:

What is exactly meant by **Current Release** on the [**Table of Hardware**](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start) page?

#### Confusion:

What I'm confused about: will **Chaos Calmer** run on these devices?

#### My thinking:

- **YES**. It's really a matter of building/compiling the package (unsure of exact terminology) for the device you're using.
- **Maybe**, (or *it probably will*), it's just that no-one has compiled it for these yet or that maybe someone has tried and were unsuccessful, gave up and moved on, and so with a little extra work/research it possibly could work
- **No**. That chipset, memory, other some other feature of the board is no longer supported and it will cause too many headaches to move on.

Just some of the notes I've made about it:

- WiFi/radio issues—not working in kernel 2.6, but worked in  2.4, what about 3+?
- [Broadcom BCM53XX](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/hardware/soc/soc.broadcom.bcm53xx)—USB and wireless, doesn't seem insurmountable
- [Broadcom BCM47xx](https://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/hardware/soc/soc.broadcom.bcm47xx)—various stuff including the page stops at **Attitue Adjustment** and **Barrier Breaker**. There's no mention of Chaos Calmer at all
- The one that has something installed is Kamakazi (unsure what version, but release 12857, so it's a bit old)
- I'm aware I can get and use 10.03.1 from the [downloads area](https://downloads.openwrt.org/) if that is as far as I can go
- I am aware of another question (which is from 2011), although he's using the Asus WL-520GU as well, it's about an [alternative to OpenWRT](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13316/good-openwrt-alternative) because of the 2.6 kernel problem, which AFAIK remains unanswered for later distros

## Finally

I'm not scared to get in there and give it a go (I really don't have much idea as to what I'm doing with building/compiling these sorts of things, but I'm adventurous) :) but I don't want to waste my time either if it's a definite 'no go'.

Comment: That is exactly as you are commenting, due to several factors, including smaller memory footprint, not all hardware supports the new openwrt versions.

Comment: Ouch, this SE is harsh. I thought I formatted and presented a question explaining my research and current thinking quite well, even if I am misunderstanding or just not getting a fundamental of the process. I do accept constructive criticism and would appreciate the neigh sayer coming forward and telling me what I can improve upon in the question. Cheers

Comment: Thanks @RuiFRibeiro I think what I mainly want to know is what is the actual limitation or what makes it unstable. From everything I've read so far, what's `unstable` are things I can do without since I really only need a small subset of components. ie, it will be providing some basic DNS functionality for a dev network plus other minor (non WiFi functions). I also have a preference for running the latest possible that way any bugs are addressed by the community at large and not simply forgotten in old versions. Given the negativity (not blaming you), I'll rework the question tonight

Comment: According to the latest information (as at 2016-06-04) it appears someone has got RPi1 (in March). I haven't had time to revisit this project, so can't confirm. Since someone has done the hard yards, I *should* revisit this again soon :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is exactly meant by Current Release on the Table of Hardware page?

If you read the "Latest Release" title from the [main page](https://wiki.openwrt.org/start) of the wiki you will notice a paragraph that says:

> The general method for picking the right image is to visit the Table of Hardware, then search for your device. **Supported devices will have a Details Page that gives instructions for installing the most recent stable firmware for your device.**

This tells you that the "Latest Release" field just informs you of the latest version that it's *known to be stable* on the device.

Comment: Thanks, I did see that, maybe I misread it, but I took that section to be more about Chaos Calmer itself (ie latest release) since even the very next paragraph directs you to try making the build yourself if the firmware isn't included on the page. I can understand now (after re-reading it) the error of my ways. Although, I would like to know more about what makes it unstable. As I alluded with the radio problem, it's certainly possible some of these things were fixed in later versions, but all that seems a little unclear. I think I'll go ahead with an upgrade to BB and see how it goes. Thanks