# Does only the current release of OpenWRT receive security updates or do all releases on the Table Of Hardware?

Tags: openwrt

Does this mean that only the current release receives updates (including security updates) and fixes while older/all other versions do not?

Quoting from the openwrt website https://downloads.openwrt.org/

" **Historic Releases**

The releases linked here are mostly for historic interest - they are long out of date and completely unmaintained. "

But on the [Table Of Hardware](https://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/start), many older versions are recommended.

A related question is asked here ([OpenWRT and Current Release Support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/253905/openwrt-and-current-release-support)) but it does not address this.